# PdfSharpCore - how to use styles

Tags: css, asp.net-core, pdf, styles

Can anyone tell me how to use styles with PdfSharpCore? I have a lot of troubles with jsreport running on OpenShift so I wanted to try PdfSharpCore but I am not able to find how to use css. With jsreport is easy, I place my css between `<style> </style>` and simply add it to the html.

style example:
`<style>.flex-box { display: flex; flex-flow: row; } .ln-title { font-size: 15px; }</style>`

For PdfSharpCore, all I found was
var font = new XFont("Arial", 20, XFontStyle.Bold);
var textColor = XBrushes.Black;
and this is not even what I need/want to achieve...

p.s. feel free to suggest some other free libraries which will work with OpenShift.

Thanks

Comment: this example can probably help you: [example](https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore/blob/master/docs/MigraDocCore/samples/Invoice.md)

Comment: thanks lordvlad30, but I had in mind to use css classes, something like <style>.flex-box {
                                        display: flex;
                                        flex-flow: row;
                                    } .ln-title {
                                        font-size: 15px;
                                    }</style>

Comment: this can maybe help: [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261981/create-pdf-from-html-snippet-using-pdfsharp-having-external-css-classes-included)

Answer (score 0):

[This library](https://github.com/j-petty/HtmlRendererCore) might be better to use stylesheets with. It is similar to PdfSharpCore, but renders HTML and CSS, making it better to use with stylesheets. I used it and it is about 3 lines to render HTML.

My recommendation would be to either read the HTML to a string from a file or use a verbatim string and replace every double quotation inside the string with two double quotations (and remove every newline). I did this by using the find and replace tool.